# What algorithm(s) to use to choose key with good occurence count but distributed value?

Tags: algorithm, distribution

I have 2 sets `A` and `B`.

There exists a table mapping elements `A` to `B`.
The only caveat is that a pair (row in table) can occur more than once.

The goal is to order elements of `A` in an order defined by the criteria :

1. Element in `A` that occurs more number of times in the table is a good element.
2. Element in `A` that is paired with the same element in `B` too many times is not good.

The above are of course qualitative and I plan to make a correct quantitative version (by how much `1` or `2` influence the notion of a good element) as I test the algorithm.

Can you suggest what algorithm(s) and data structures I should look at (if there already exist any)?

**EDIT :** In general if a decision of which element comes before which, depends on 2 factors that are hardly linear, how is it written?

In my case, 
an element in `A` which is almost fully paired with the same element in `B` everywhere it occurs, is a very "less" element. It comes after everything else even if it has a huge occurrence count.

I somehow find this very confusing and want to know if there is some resource/study that deals with this kind of stuff.

Comment: you can create a new table with the following field: Some_identifier, COUNT_in_A, COUNT_in_B. This is a very ill posed problem. Now wonder you are confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a structure that is essentially:

```
struct
{
    Element  // 'A', for example
    Count    // total number of 'A' elements
    HashMap(Element, count) // A hash map keyed by element ('B', for example),
                            // count is the number of times A is paired with B
    Value   // computed "quality", based on your criteria
}
```

If you go through the mapping table and build a list of those structures, you then have a count for each element, and for each element the number of times it is paired with each other element.

You can then use your criteria to determine each element's value, and finally sort by that value.

How you compute the value is an open question. A good place to start would be to sum the values 1/sqrt(count). The table below shows element A paired with elements B, C, and D a number of times, and the resulting values for each pairing:

```
A  B   1   1/sqrt(1)  = 1/1
A  C   4   1/sqrt(4)  = 1/2
A  D  16   1/sqrt(16) = 1/4
```

So A's total score would be 1 + 0.5 + 0.25, or 1.75

You'd have to play with the formula to meet your needs. Dividing by the count, I've found, is too much of a hit (i.e. A-D would give 1/16). Dividing by the square root helps minimize the overactive items, but doesn't completely discount them.

Comment: Thank you. There doesn't seem to be a perfect solution. Are there any  distribution algorithms out there that will tell you how "well distributed" a sequence of numbers are?